# Elasticsearch query based on properties of another document

Tags: elasticsearch

Is there a way in ES to do a single query that finds documents that are based on values "close" (whose logic I determine) to values in another document?

Example: i have document like this:

```
{
   "myId": 10,
   "price": 200
}
```

Now I want to run a query that finds documents that are within 100 either side of the price of the above document (but I don't know the price of document on the client..all I have is the `myId`)

In other words, i want to write a client method like this:

`GetSimilarDocuments(int myId);`

Is that possible to do in a *single* ES query? Or do I need two round trips? (get the document, then do another query based on the values of the document)

Comment: Can't you do two queries? One to grab the price of id 10, then another query to grab the documents where `100 <= price <= 300`

Comment: Maybe this can help you: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.x/query-dsl-terms-query.html#query-dsl-terms-lookup

Comment: @EliasSoares yes - i can do two queries (as i said in the last paragraph), however i'm trying to avoid that, for performance reasons. Link is close, but not quite what i'm after. Terms lookup is based on the same values of another document. I'm wanting based on special logic. Also, i don't have the internal id, i have another field (i'll update my question).

Comment: Yes... This terms query won't do it since it doesn't support a range but a single value. Probably the only way is using some scripted field or a script query... (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.x/query-dsl-script-query.html) but I think this will be much more complicated and slower then doing two separate queries. Sorry can't go deeper on this because I'm writing from mobile now.

Comment: I think even with `script` it can not be done in one query. The reason is the first `match : {id: 10}` only gets you one document so having `price range` does not help. I would like to see your answer @EliasSoares

Comment: i ended up doing two queries for now. keeping this question open, as i'm still curious if it can be done in a performant/non-complex way.